# How to get the selected options from dropdown and multiply with input fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Hi I am trying to perform a check on whether the user selected a given item from a dropdown and according to it's selection perform a multiplication with three different items and render the result.

I want to get i.e: if lamp is selected then make lamp * hours * qty * watts;
then get: ac * hours * qty * watts,
and finally: tv * hours * qty * watts,

and then get all the total in an array and render it to the user in the;

This is my html`

```
<form action="" id="energyForm">
               <label for=""></label>
                  <select id="houseSet" onselect="getSelectValue();">
                        <option id="lamp" value="lamp">Lamp</option>
                        <option id="AC" value="ac">Air Conditioner</option>
                        <option id="TV" value="tv">TV</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="15" id="qty" placeholder="Qty">
                    <input type="number" min="1" id="watts" placeholder="Watts">
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="24" id="hours" placeholder="Hours of Use">
                    <input type="text" id="subtotal" placeholder="Daily SubTotal">
                    <input type="text" id="total" placeholder="Daily Total">
                    <button name="calculate" id="itemConsumption" onclick="">Item Consumption</button>
                    <button name="calculus" id="totalConsumption" onclick="calculate();">Total</button>
                    <button name="">Clear Input</button>
                    <button name="">Remove Data</button>
                </form>
```

`

```
// Calculate all the consumed watts
    function calculate() {
        // inputing the variable into an array
        let items = [lamp, AC, TV];
        for (i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
            return i * qty * watts * hoursUsed;
        }
    }
```

`

`

Comment: Add your code for `function` `calculate()` to your post. What you posted is not code, it's `Html`

Comment: You are pretty close, but you need to use the DOM to get the values from the input elements in your `calculate` function. [Here is a link that shows you how to get a reference to HTML elements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp). Once you have the reference then you'll need to [get the values](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using body-parser in node, you can add a name to your select tag:

```
<select name='myselect'>
```

And in node, you can access the option the user selects with `req.body.myselect`

Comment: Seems like the question is more about client-side code, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @Ank i zle I will apply the suggestion you made and will get back with the result. Thanks man.